# How to do Apple Watch Background App Refresh?

Tags: swift, watchos

I've consulted many variations of background app refresh for Apple Watch so that I can update the complications for my app. However, the process seems very much hit or miss and most of the time it doesn't run at all after some time.

Here is the code I currently have:

BackgroundService.swift
Responsibility: Schedule background refresh and handle download processing and update complications.

```swift
import Foundation
import WatchKit

final class BackgroundService: NSObject, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    var isStarted = false
    private let requestFactory: RequestFactory
    private let logManager: LogManager
    private let complicationService: ComplicationService
    private let notificationService: NotificationService
    private var pendingBackgroundTask: WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask?
    private var backgroundSession: URLSession?

    init(requestFactory: RequestFactory,
         logManager: LogManager,
         complicationService: ComplicationService,
         notificationService: NotificationService
        ) {
        self.requestFactory = requestFactory
        self.logManager = logManager
        self.complicationService = complicationService
        self.notificationService = notificationService
        super.init()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(handleInitialSchedule(_:)),
                                               name: Notification.Name("ScheduleBackgroundTasks"),
                                               object: nil
                                              )
    }

    func updateContent() {
        self.logManager.debugMessage("In BackgroundService updateContent")
        let complicationsUpdateRequest = self.requestFactory.makeComplicationsUpdateRequest()

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "app.wakawatch.background-refresh")
        config.isDiscretionary = false
        config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true

        self.backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: config,
                                 delegate: self,
                                 delegateQueue: nil)

        let backgroundTask = self.backgroundSession?.downloadTask(with: complicationsUpdateRequest)
        backgroundTask?.resume()
        self.isStarted = true
        self.logManager.debugMessage("backgroundTask started")
    }

    func handleDownload(_ backgroundTask: WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask) {
        self.logManager.debugMessage("Handling finished download")
        self.pendingBackgroundTask = backgroundTask
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        processFile(file: location)
        self.logManager.debugMessage("Marking pending background tasks as completed.")

        if self.pendingBackgroundTask != nil {
            self.pendingBackgroundTask?.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
            self.backgroundSession?.invalidateAndCancel()
            self.pendingBackgroundTask = nil
            self.backgroundSession = nil
            self.logManager.debugMessage("Pending background task cleared")
        }

        self.schedule()
    }

    func processFile(file: URL) {
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: file) else {
            self.logManager.errorMessage("file could not be read as data")
            return
        }

        guard let backgroundUpdateResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(BackgroundUpdateResponse.self, from: data) else {
            self.logManager.errorMessage("Unable to decode response to Swift object")
            return
        }

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(backgroundUpdateResponse.totalTimeCodedInSeconds,
                    forKey: DefaultsKeys.complicationCurrentTimeCoded)
        self.complicationService.updateTimelines()
        self.notificationService.isPermissionGranted(onGrantedHandler: {
            self.notificationService.notifyGoalsAchieved(newGoals: backgroundUpdateResponse.goals)
        })
        self.logManager.debugMessage("Complication updated")
    }

    func schedule() {
        let time = self.isStarted ? 15 * 60 : 60
        let nextInterval = TimeInterval(time)
        let preferredDate = Date.now.addingTimeInterval(nextInterval)

        WKExtension.shared().scheduleBackgroundRefresh(withPreferredDate: preferredDate,
                                                       userInfo: nil) { error in
            if error != nil {
                self.logManager.reportError(error!)
                return
            }

            self.logManager.debugMessage("Scheduled for \(preferredDate)")
        }
    }

    @objc func handleInitialSchedule(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        if !self.isStarted {
            self.schedule()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

The flow for the above file's usage is that it will be used by the ExtensionDelegate to schedule background refresh. The first time, it'll schedule a refresh for 1 minute out and then every 15 minutes after that.

Here is the ExtensionDelegate:

```swift
import Foundation
import WatchKit

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {
    private var backgroundService: BackgroundService?
    private var logManager: LogManager?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.backgroundService = DependencyInjection.shared.container.resolve(BackgroundService.self)!
        self.logManager = DependencyInjection.shared.container.resolve(LogManager.self)!
    }

    func isAuthorized() -> Bool {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        return defaults.bool(forKey: DefaultsKeys.authorized)
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        self.logManager?.debugMessage("In applicationDidFinishLaunching")
        if isAuthorized() && !(self.backgroundService?.isStarted ?? false) {
            self.backgroundService?.schedule()
        }
    }

    func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
        self.logManager?.debugMessage("In handle backgroundTasks")
        if !isAuthorized() {
            return
        }

        for task in backgroundTasks {
            self.logManager?.debugMessage("Processing task: \(task.debugDescription)")
            switch task {
            case let backgroundTask as WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask:
                self.backgroundService?.updateContent()
                backgroundTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
            case let urlSessionTask as WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask:
                self.backgroundService?.handleDownload(urlSessionTask)
            default:
                task.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the app is launched from background, it'll try to schedule for the first time in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

From my understanding, `WKExtension.shared().scheduleBackgroundRefresh` will get called in schedule, then after the preferred time WatchOS will call handle with `WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask` task. Then I will use that to schedule a background URL session task and immediately start it as seen in the `updateContent` method of `BackgroundService`. After some time, WatchOS will then call ExtensionDelegate's handle method with `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask` and I'll handle that using the `handleDownload` task. In there, I process the response, update the complications, clear the task, and finally schedule a new background refresh.

I've found it works great if I'm actively working on the app or interacting with it in general. But let's say I go to sleep then the next day the complication will not have updated at all.

Ideally, I'd like for it to function as well as the Weather app complication WatchOS has. I don't interact with the complication, but it reliably updates.

Is the above process correct or are there any samples of correct implementations?

Some of the posts I've consulted:
https://wjwickham.com/posts/refreshing-data-in-the-background-on-watchOS/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/background_execution/using_background_tasks

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2021/01/26/complications-basic-functionality/